# Recording audio in Swift

Tags: audio, swift

Does anyone know where I can find info on how to record audio in a Swift application? I've been looking at some of the audio playback examples but I can't seem to be able to find anything on implementing the audio recording. Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is code.You can record easily.Write this code on `IBAction`.It will save the recording in `Documents` by name `recordTest.caf`

```
//declare instance variable 
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
func record(){        
    var audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
    audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

    var documents: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,  NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    var str =  documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
    var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(str as String)

    var recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
        AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue]

    println("url : \(url)")
    var error: NSError?

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL:url, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
    if let e = error {
        println(e.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        audioRecorder.record()
    }        
}
```

Comment: `documents` should be `(documents as NSString).append...` (var str declaration code)

Answer (score 70):

**In Swift 3**

[image]

- **Add framework AVFoundation**
- **In info.plist add key value

> **Key** = Privacy - Microphone Usage Description and  **Value** = For using
>   microphone

(the apps will crash if you don't provide the value  - description why you are asking for the permission)**

[image]

- **Import AVFoundation & AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate**

  ```
  import AVFoundation

   class RecordVC: UIViewController , AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate
  ```
- **Create button for record audio & play audio , and label for display recording timing & give outlets and action as start_recording , play_recording & declare some variables which we will use later**

  ```
  @IBOutlet var recordingTimeLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var record_btn_ref: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var play_btn_ref: UIButton!

  var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
  var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
  var meterTimer:Timer!
  var isAudioRecordingGranted: Bool!
  var isRecording = false
  var isPlaying = false
  ```
- **In viewDidLoad check record permission**

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      check_record_permission()
  }

  func check_record_permission()
  {
      switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
      case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
          isAudioRecordingGranted = true
          break
      case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
          isAudioRecordingGranted = false
          break
      case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
          AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (allowed) in
                  if allowed {
                      self.isAudioRecordingGranted = true
                  } else {
                      self.isAudioRecordingGranted = false
                  }
          })
          break
      default:
          break
      }
  }
  ```
- **generate path where you want to save that recording as myRecording.m4a**

  ```
  func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL
  {
      let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
      let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
      return documentsDirectory
  }

  func getFileUrl() -> URL
  {
      let filename = "myRecording.m4a"
      let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(filename)
  return filePath
  }
  ```
- **Setup the recorder**

  ```
  func setup_recorder()
  {
      if isAudioRecordingGranted
      {
          let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
          do
          {
              try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
              try session.setActive(true)
              let settings = [
                  AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                  AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
              ]
              audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileUrl(), settings: settings)
              audioRecorder.delegate = self
              audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
              audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
          }
          catch let error {
              display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: error.localizedDescription, action_title: "OK")
          }
      }
      else
      {
          display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: "Don't have access to use your microphone.", action_title: "OK")
      }
  }
  ```
- **Start recording when button start_recording press & display seconds using updateAudioMeter, & if recording is start then finish the recording**

  ```
  @IBAction func start_recording(_ sender: UIButton)
  {
      if(isRecording)
      {
          finishAudioRecording(success: true)
          record_btn_ref.setTitle("Record", for: .normal)
          play_btn_ref.isEnabled = true
          isRecording = false
      }
      else
      {
          setup_recorder()

          audioRecorder.record()
          meterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector:#selector(self.updateAudioMeter(timer:)), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
          record_btn_ref.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
          play_btn_ref.isEnabled = false
          isRecording = true
      }
  }

  func updateAudioMeter(timer: Timer)
  {
      if audioRecorder.isRecording
      {
          let hr = Int((audioRecorder.currentTime / 60) / 60)
          let min = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime / 60)
          let sec = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
          let totalTimeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec)
          recordingTimeLabel.text = totalTimeString
          audioRecorder.updateMeters()
      }
  }

  func finishAudioRecording(success: Bool)
  {
      if success
      {
          audioRecorder.stop()
          audioRecorder = nil
          meterTimer.invalidate()
          print("recorded successfully.")
      }
      else
      {
          display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: "Recording failed.", action_title: "OK")
      }
  }
  ```
- **Play the recording**

  ```
  func prepare_play()
  {
      do
      {
          audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: getFileUrl())
          audioPlayer.delegate = self
          audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
      }
      catch{
          print("Error")
      }
  }

  @IBAction func play_recording(_ sender: Any)
  {
      if(isPlaying)
      {
          audioPlayer.stop()
          record_btn_ref.isEnabled = true
          play_btn_ref.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
          isPlaying = false
      }
      else
      {
          if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: getFileUrl().path)
          {
              record_btn_ref.isEnabled = false
              play_btn_ref.setTitle("pause", for: .normal)
              prepare_play()
              audioPlayer.play()
              isPlaying = true
          }
          else
          {
              display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: "Audio file is missing.", action_title: "OK")
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **When recording is finish enable the play button & when play is finish enable the record button**

  ```
  func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool)
  {
      if !flag
      {
          finishAudioRecording(success: false)
      }
      play_btn_ref.isEnabled = true
  }

  func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
  {
      record_btn_ref.isEnabled = true
  }
  ```
- **Generalize function for display alert**

  ```
  func display_alert(msg_title : String , msg_desc : String ,action_title : String)
  {
      let ac = UIAlertController(title: msg_title, message: msg_desc, preferredStyle: .alert)
      ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action_title, style: .default)
      {
          (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
      _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
      })
      present(ac, animated: true)
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you add pause and continue functionality to this?

Comment: @Mamta whenever i will get time definitely i will do it.

Comment: @MiliShah wow Mili.. So well explained...! When are you implementing the feature that Mamta requested? waiting for it. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Thanks ... actually I am busy in project but i will implement as soon as possible .

Comment: Can you update the answer to say 'conform to AVAudioRecorderDelegate & AVAudioPlayerDelegate' rather than import please as it is clearer on bullet-point 3? Thanks

Comment: @MiliShah: Does this code record the streaming audio or output audio?

Answer (score 16):

Swift2 version of @codester's answer.

```
func record() {
    //init
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    //ask for permission
    if (audioSession.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")) {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
            if granted {
                print("granted")

                //set category and activate recorder session
                try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                try! audioSession.setActive(true)


                //get documnets directory
                let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
                let fullPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("voiceRecording.caf")
                let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fullPath)

                //create AnyObject of settings
                let settings: [String : AnyObject] = [
                    AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatAppleIMA4), //Int required in Swift2
                    AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,
                    AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
                    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue
                ]

                //record
                try! self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: settings)

            } else{
                print("not granted")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey - After testing out this code, I get "stringByAppendingPathComponent is unavailable, try URLByAppendingPathComponent" on the fullPath line, however that doesn't work because there is no such method for fullPath's type.

Comment: @LiamShalon are you sure you properly set up the `documentsDirectory` var? if it isn't set properly, then the `stringByAppendingPathComponent` wont exist.

Comment: Some of the string extensions disappeared when apple launched swift 2.0. Check this link for creating the extension manually: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580

Comment: Hey, I think you should add `self.audioRecorder.record()` after `try! self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: settings)`. Moreover, documentsDirectory is not a string, so you should put `(documentsDirectory as NSString).stringby...`

Answer (score 7):

In addition to previous answers, I tried to make it work on Xcode 7.2 and I couldn't hear any sound after, neither when I sent the file via email. No warning or exception.
So I changed settings to the following and stored as an .m4a file.

```
let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue))]
```

After that I could listen to sound.
For saving the file, I added this on viewDidLoad to initialise the recorder:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL()!,
            settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {
    }
```

And for creating the directory:

```
func directoryURL() -> NSURL? {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL 
}
```

I also add the actions used to start recording, stop, and play after

```
@IBAction func doRecordAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioRecorder.recording {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            audioRecorder.record()
        } catch {
        }
   }
}
@IBAction func doStopRecordingAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
    } catch {
    }
}

@IBAction func doPlayAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (!audioRecorder.recording){
        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioRecorder.url)
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For swift 2 and Xcode 7.2 this is should the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: and, how to send file by email ?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/sssbohdan/0cad6dacdb692e7890f1d9048008eef1) audio recorder with simple interface written on Swift 4.2 .

```
final class AudioRecorderImpl: NSObject {
  private let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  private var player: AVAudioPlayer?
  private var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?
  private lazy var permissionGranted = false
  private lazy var isRecording = false
  private lazy var isPlaying = false
  private var fileURL: URL?
  private let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
  ]

  override init() {
    fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("note.m4a")
  }

  func record(to url: URL?) {
    guard permissionGranted,
      let url = url ?? fileURL else { return }

    setupRecorder(url: url)

    if isRecording {
      stopRecording()
    }

    isRecording = true
    recorder?.record()
  }

  func stopRecording() {
    isRecording = false
    recorder?.stop()
    try? session.setActive(false)
  }

  func play(from url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url ?? fileURL else { return }

    setupPlayer(url: url)

    if isRecording {
      stopRecording()
    }

    if isPlaying {
      stopPlaying()
    }

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
      isPlaying = true
      setupPlayer(url: url)
      player?.play()
    }
  }

  func stopPlaying() {
    player?.stop()
  }

  func pause() {
    player?.pause()
  }

  func resume() {
    if player?.isPlaying == false {
      player?.play()
    }
  }

  func checkPermission(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
    func assignAndInvokeCallback(_ granted: Bool) {
      self.permissionGranted = granted
      completion?(granted)
    }

    switch session.recordPermission {
    case .granted:
      assignAndInvokeCallback(true)

    case .denied:
      assignAndInvokeCallback(false)

    case .undetermined:
      session.requestRecordPermission(assignAndInvokeCallback)
    }
  }
}

extension AudioRecorderImpl: AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

}

private extension AudioRecorderImpl {
  func setupRecorder(url: URL) {
    guard
      permissionGranted else { return }
    try? session.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
    try? session.setActive(true)
    let settings = [
      AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
      AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
    recorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: settings)
    recorder?.delegate = self
    recorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
    recorder?.prepareToRecord()
  }

  func setupPlayer(url: URL) {
    player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    player?.delegate = self
    player?.prepareToPlay()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 5**,

```
 func setup_recorder()
{
    if isAudioRecordingGranted
    {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do
        {
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try session.setActive(true)
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileUrl(), settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        }
        catch let error {
            display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: error.localizedDescription, action_title: "OK")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        display_alert(msg_title: "Error", msg_desc: "Don't have access to use your microphone.", action_title: "OK")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code in Class file Using Swift 4**

Class is [AGAudioRecorder](https://gist.github.com/AshvinGudaliya/e8d18281e16cbe75971581c188e308dd)

Code is

```
class AudioRecordViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var recodeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!

    var state: AGAudioRecorderState = .Ready

    var recorder: AGAudioRecorder = AGAudioRecorder(withFileName: "TempFile")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        recodeBtn.setTitle("Recode", for: .normal)
        playBtn.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        recorder.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func recode(_ sender: UIButton) {
        recorder.doRecord()
    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
        recorder.doPlay()
    }
}

extension AudioRecordViewController: AGAudioRecorderDelegate {
    func agAudioRecorder(_ recorder: AGAudioRecorder, withStates state: AGAudioRecorderState) {
        switch state {
        case .error(let e): debugPrint(e)
        case .Failed(let s): debugPrint(s)

        case .Finish:
            recodeBtn.setTitle("Recode", for: .normal)

        case .Recording:
            recodeBtn.setTitle("Recoding Finished", for: .normal)

        case .Pause:
            playBtn.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)

        case .Play:
            playBtn.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)

        case .Ready:
            recodeBtn.setTitle("Recode", for: .normal)
            playBtn.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
            refreshBtn.setTitle("Refresh", for: .normal)
        }
        debugPrint(state)
    }

    func agAudioRecorder(_ recorder: AGAudioRecorder, currentTime timeInterval: TimeInterval, formattedString: String) {
        debugPrint(formattedString)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use your code for commercial app? (or I can create my own by looking at your code)

Comment: Right now i am working on this code also and upload on git repository ASAP. this wrapper class create for my app and some other person use so i uploaded public. If you create good then share me so i help on your code also

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Code Version: Complete Solution for Audio Recording!**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var recordingTimeLabel: UILabel!

    //Variables
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var meterTimer:Timer!
    var isAudioRecordingGranted: Bool!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
            isAudioRecordingGranted = true
            break
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
            isAudioRecordingGranted = false
            break
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        self.isAudioRecordingGranted = true
                    } else {
                        self.isAudioRecordingGranted = false
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        audioRecorder = nil
    }

    //MARK:- Audio recorder buttons action.
    @IBAction func audioRecorderAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if isAudioRecordingGranted {

            //Create the session.
            let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

            do {
                //Configure the session for recording and playback.
                try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
                try session.setActive(true)
                //Set up a high-quality recording session.
                let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]
                //Create audio file name URL
                let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("audioRecording.m4a")
                //Create the audio recording, and assign ourselves as the delegate
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
                audioRecorder.record()
                meterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector:#selector(self.updateAudioMeter(timer:)), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Error for start audio recording: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopAudioRecordingAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        finishAudioRecording(success: true)

    }

    func finishAudioRecording(success: Bool) {

        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil
        meterTimer.invalidate()

        if success {
            print("Recording finished successfully.")
        } else {
            print("Recording failed :(")
        }
    }

    func updateAudioMeter(timer: Timer) {

        if audioRecorder.isRecording {
            let hr = Int((audioRecorder.currentTime / 60) / 60)
            let min = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime / 60)
            let sec = Int(audioRecorder.currentTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
            let totalTimeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec)
            recordingTimeLabel.text = totalTimeString
            audioRecorder.updateMeters()
        }
    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {

        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

    //MARK:- Audio recoder delegate methods
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {

        if !flag {
            finishAudioRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add pause and continue functionality to this?

Comment: Hi @Mamta, Could you please submit a new question? So I can answer it because I need to use different delegate for playing audio with play, pause and stop feature. I hope you understand it. This page is only for audio recording. Please give the URL of question here. Thanks - mriaz0011

Comment: @mriaz0011: Does this code record the live stream audio or output audio?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple 2022 syntax, record audio on iPhone.

Older answers don't work.

Needed ...

```
var mic: AVAudioRecorder?

var workingFile: URL {
    return FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("temp.m4a")
}
```

And then

```
@IBAction public func tapTalkSend() {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
    case .authorized: _talkSend()
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) {  [weak self] granted in
            if granted { self?._talkSend() }
        }
    case .denied: return
    case .restricted: return
    @unknown default:
        return
    }
}
```

And then

```
public func _talkSend() {
    if mic != nil && mic!.isRecording {
        mic?.stop()
        mic = nil
        return
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        mic = try AVAudioRecorder(url: workingFile, settings: [:])
    }
    catch let error {
        return print("mic drama \(error)")
    }
    
    mic!.delegate = self
    mic!.record()
}
```

Add `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` on your vc. And:

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    _testPlay() ...
    _sendFileSomewhere() ...
}
func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, error: Error?) {
    print("audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur")
}
```

To test by playing it back:

```
var myPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func _testPlay() {
    do {
        myPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: workingFile)
        myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        myPlayer.play()
    }
    catch let error {
        return print("play drama \(error)")
    }
}
```

In your plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>For spoken messages.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>For spoken messages.</string>
```