# Using AVAudioRecorder to record voice

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to make a simple voice recorder. I'm using Xcode-beta 7 and I've based my code off of these three sources.

- [AVFoundation Audio Recording With Swift](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/avfoundation-audio-recording-with-swift/)
- [AVAudioRecorder Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/initWithURL:settings:error:) to see the inputs of the initializers.
- [Recording audio in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472747/recording-audio-in-swift) to get the Settings that I should use

I'm using the following code:

```
var recordSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey: 32000
    ]

    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: recordSettings, error: nil)
    }catch{
        print("Error")
    }
```

but it says that "Cannot find an initializer for type 'AVAudioRecorder' that accepts an argument list of type '(URL:NSURL?, settings:[String:AudioFormatID], error:nil)'"

Aren't my inputs exactly what the documentation asks for?

Comment: I'm having this EXACT same problem right now! When I create the recordSettings dictionary I get an error "AudioFormatID does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'". Are you having that issue too?

Comment: because you are passing Int and not object. Try to create an NSNumber instead like I show in my answer: NSNumber(integer: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVAudioRecorder does not need anymore the error parameter:

```
init(URL url: NSURL, settings settings: [String : AnyObject]) throws
```

Also, I needed to unwrap the filePath, as suggested in a previous answer:

```
func recordSound(){
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let recordingName = "my_audio.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    let recordSettings = [AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Min.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]
    print(filePath)

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath!, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
    } catch _ {
        print("Error")
    }

    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes my build succeed but I haven't tested out the actual recording yet. Also I moved this code segment from viewDidLoad into the action for the record button. Do you have any idea why it might not have worked in viewDidLoad? I thought it made sense to put it there because you want everything to load before you hit the record button.

Comment: It makes sense to move it into viewDidLoad, but leave the last 2 lines for the record button.

Comment: what does audioRecorder.delegate = self do? because if I include that I can't seem to get it to compile. When I run it without that though, I get a Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0x0)

Comment: The audio recorder needs a delegate, because it has to know what to do when recording is finished. So, you also need to implement the protocol: AVAudioRecorderDelegate in the RecordSoundsViewController, like this:                                                               `class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate`

Comment: And also implement the method from AVAudioRecorderDelegate `func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool)`

Answer (score 0):

Your filePath is wrapped as an optionnal. You should check if isn't nil and unwrap it like this:

```
recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath!, settings: recordSettings, error: nil)
```

And you need to pass an NSError pointer too:

```
var error: NSError?
recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath!, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
```

After that, if you have error in your settings dictionnay, try to transform all Tnt to NSNumber, because NSNumber is an Object, not Int. Example:

```
NSNumber(integer: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4)
```

Comment: With your NSNumber suggestion, it still gives a similar error: 'AudioFormatID' is not convertible to 'Int'.  EDIT: Just give it 'unsignedInt' instead of 'integer' and it seems to work. AudioFormatID is a UInt32.