# How to record Audio When video is going

Tags: ios, swift, record

I'm successfully able to record audio by using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472747/recording-audio-in-swift). Now my problem is that there is an option to start video call (Using Twiliio). During video I'm not able to hear anything in my recorded audio. But once video call ends I'm able to hear the recorded voice.

How to record audio during video call also?

Thank you....

Comment: So what you are trying to do is record audio while another app is active? If that's the case, I would think that's impossible, due to security concerns

Comment: No My app is Active? User can able to make a video call from my app it self,

Comment: ohk.. when you started video player did you try to start your own AVAudioSession.

Comment: Acually Im Uisng "TwilioConversationsClient" for Video Session