# Uploading recording to Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, avfoundation, firebase-storage

I've been trying to upload audio recording right after user stops recording to the Firebase. But it doesn't do anything apart from creating a new folder named "audio".

Code I'm using for starting and stopping recording

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress"
    stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
    recordButton.isEnabled = false

    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}


@IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Stop recording button was pressed")
    recordButton.isEnabled = true
    stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
    recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setActive(false)
}
```

code I'm using for uploading to Firebase

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finished recording")


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("audio/recordedVoice.wav")

    if let uploadData = AVFileType(self.recordedVoice.wav!) {

        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) {(metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 let audioName = NSUUID().uuidString //You'll get unique audioFile name
 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("audio").child(audioName)
 let metadata  = StorageMetadata()
 metadata.contentType = "audio/wav"
 if let uploadData = AVFileType(self.recordedVoice.wav!) {

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, err) in
            if err != nil {
                //print(err)
                return
            }
            if let _ = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                print("uploading done!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'recordedVoice'".

Comment: @Joel Try record your audio like this: [Another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187539/9766784)

Comment: Ok I will... Thanks :) Will update here if it works.

Answer (score 0):

so I have been working on this for hours and here is my answer:

```swift
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {  
           let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
           return paths[0]
       }
    func getFileURL() -> URL {
        let path = getDocumentsDirectory()
        let filePath = path.appendingPathComponent(K.fileName)
        
        return filePath
    }

 let referance = storage.reference()
        let mediaFolder = referance.child("media")
        let id = UUID().uuidString // using uuid to give uniq names to audiofiles preventing overwrite
        let mediaRef = mediaFolder.child(id + K.fileName) // creating file referance using uuid + filename
        let path = getFileURL() // getting filepath
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: path) // getting data from filepath
            mediaRef.putData(data) { metadata, error in
                if error != nil {
                    self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, cancelButtonTitle: "cancel", handler: nil)
                } else {
                    mediaRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                        let url = url?.absoluteString
                        print(url)
                    }
                }
            }
            print("record has come")
        } catch {
            print("error cant get audio file")
        }
```

I'm relatively new at coding and still learning. So that my answer may not be the best and shortest. But This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).