# How to stream audio while recording in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop a audio streaming system. The client streams the audio from microphone to server while recording in real-time, another clients will subscribe like podcast.

As far as my understanding, the `AVCaptureSession` derives the `AVCaptureDeviceInput` to `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`.

```swift
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) else { return }

let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)

if captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput) {
    captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
}

let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
if captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput) {
    captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
}

captureSession.commitConfiguration()
```

With a background from javascript with `MediaRecoder` API. The recoder emits a chunk of audio data every X milliseconds.

So, Is it possible to do a similar way in iOS (swift)? Is there any other way to do stream the audio in real-time

Edit 1: I need a stream or a chunk of data that emit every X miliseconds. [This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472747/recording-audio-in-swift) mentioned the recording but it saved to the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recording audio in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472747/recording-audio-in-swift)

Comment: No, The answer record the audio to the file. But I need a stream, not a file.